# display multiple xml node into datagridview using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have xml file, i displayed the first node within form in c#, this node have attribute is called 'id', now i want to display all nodes that have attribute is called 'father' its value equal to id value.
xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tree>
   <grand name ="aaa" id="1" sex="m" status="d" child="2" father=""></grand>
   <grand name="bbb"  id="11" sex="m" status="d" child="1" father="1"></grand> 
   <grand name="ccc" id="111" sex="m" status="d" child="1"  father="11"></grand>  
   <grand name="ddd" id="1111" sex="m" status="d" child="3"  father="111"></grand>  
   <grand name="eee" id="11111" sex="f" status="d" child=""  father="1111"></grand>  
   <grand name="fff"  id="11112" sex="m" status="d" child="" father="1111"></grand>
</tree>
```

c# code:

```
 InitializeComponent();
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(" http://domaim.net/tree/index.xml");
 var name = xdoc.Descendants("grand").First().Attribute("name").Value;
 var sex = xdoc.Descendants("grand").First().Attribute("sex").Value;
 var alive = xdoc.Descendants("grand").First().Attribute("status").Value;
 var child = xdoc.Descendants("grand").First().Attribute("child").Value;
 var id = xdoc.Descendants("grand").First().Attribute("id").Value;
 var father = xdoc.Descendants("grand").First().Attribute("father").Value;
 textBox1.Text = name;
 if (sex == "m") textBox2.Text = "male"; else textBox2.Text = "female";
 if (child == "") textBox4.Text = "no child"; else textBox4.Text = child;
 if (alive == "d") textBox3.Text = "dead"; else textBox3.Text = "alive";
```

thank you for all

Comment: So, you want to display some specific nodes... and what is your question?

Comment: I want to display attributes of some node within datagridview, so I want display all nodes that its attribute 'id' match specified number. Thank you Nadia Chibrikova.

Comment: I got that, but what is your problem? You don't know how to select nodes or how to bind them to a datagrid?

Comment: Yes, I do not know how I can bind them to a datagrid, thank you Nadia Chibrikova.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to XML and do something like this:

```
 datagrid.DataSource = (from n in doc.Descendants("grand")
                         where n.Attribute("father").Value==id
                             select new{
                                 Name = n.Attribute("name").Value,
                                 Sex = n.Attribute("sex").Value,
                                 Id = n.Attribute("id").Value,
                                 Status = n.Attribute("status").Value,
                                 Child = n.Attribute("child").Value,
                                 Father = n.Attribute("father").Value
                             }).ToList();
```

Hope it's what you're trying to achieve :)

Comment: i get this error message:  (Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'ItemsSource' and no extension method 'ItemsSource' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\olwan\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\famillytree\famillytree\form1.cs 34 22 famillytree
) thank you Ndia Chibrikova

Comment: Ah, it was for WPF, you need to use DataSource instead. I've changed it in the answer.

Comment: hello Nadia Chibrikova. please I searched but i faild, i want ask you, how i set the attribute of node as text value of textbox control. thank you

Comment: You can do it in the same way as you assign variables in your code snippet: `textBox.Text = node.Attribute("name").Value;`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am sorry  Nadia Chibrikova, I am new in c#. I want ask to do new search withen the xml nodes according to given id attribute, the result node, i will set its attributes as text values for textboxes. thank you very much

Comment: To select a node by attribute use `var node = doc.Descendants("NodeName").Where(n => n.Attribute("AttributeName").Value == "value").First();`. Do you have any problems with your original question? You've marked it as unanswered.

Comment: Thank you Nadia Chibrikova, I already learn c#, and I think dealing with xml easy more than dealing with database, I deal with database it did not need more work, ok perhaps I do some thing wrong, I will relearn dealing with xml. Thank you very much.